# How to call thunked action creator outside of react component with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I have a thunked store created like

```
export const store = createStore<IState, IAction<string, any>, {}, {}>(combinedReducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

I want to dispatch a thunked action outside of a React component, like `store.dispatch(myThunkedActionCreator(data));`

However, the type of `dispatch` is coming in as `Dispatch<IAction<string, any>>` instead of `ThunkDispatch<State, void, ActionType>`, which would be the type necessary to pass a thunk to the store's modified dispatch. I import the store as `import { store } from '../Store/Store';`

How can I get `store.dispatch` to have the right, thunked dispatch type?

I know I can typecast `dispatch` at its callsites, but that's a hack. I'm not currently using RTK, which solves the typing problem, but that's out of scope for me at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple problems here.

The first is that **we have officially deprecated the original `createStore` API from the core `redux` package, and we do *not* want people using that directly in their applications!**  Instead, you *should* be using the `configureStore` API from our official Redux Toolkit package, which wraps `createStore` and sets it up with a good default configuration:

- https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux#using-configurestore
- https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/releases/tag/v4.2.0

The second issue is that by explicitly adding generics to `createStore`, you're overriding any possible type inference that TS might do from the provided middleware like `thunk`.  So, as far as TS is concerned, `store.dispatch` is still only the "basic" type that can only accept action objects - the thunk middleware modifications (which tell TS it can also accept a thunk function) are being ignored and overridden by those generics.

The best answer here is to use `configureStore`, which automatically adds the thunk middleware anyway, *and* has better TS inference for any customizations:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit" 

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: combinedReducers
})

// already added the thunk middleware!
store.dispatch(myThunk())

// TS types reflect that:
// ThunkDispatch & Dispatch<AnyAction>
type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

Comment: Yeah, guess I'll have to do that eventually. One thing I don't like about allowing TS to do type inference of my state is that it can introduce weird bugs in what my state's shape actually turns out to be, whereas if I have an explicit IState, I know exactly what the state will be.

Comment: Our recommendations are to explicitly type each _individual_ slice's state, like `TodosState` or `PostsState`... but then _infer_ the _root_ state.  That way as you do add more slices, you don't have to keep updating that type directly (ie, only do the store setup process once). See https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start . Plus, for _both_ `createStore` and `configureStore`, adding the actual state type as a generic argument will end up breaking the type inference overall.